# Stacking divs while loading

Tags: html

I'm creating a fake loading of divs to show the user while the result is loading. It is working fine, but I need the divs to push each other down when new div is loading, not like is doing now, loading one after other. Also, I can't use position absolute/relative bc, it will not work in all the browsers. If any one have any idea, let me know. Thanks

```css
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 1em;
}

.card {
  animation: slide 0.5s linear both;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-5vh);
}

.card:nth-of-type(10) {
  animation-delay: 10s;
}

.card:nth-of-type(9) {
  animation-delay: 9s;
}

.card:nth-of-type(8) {
  animation-delay: 8s;
}

.card:nth-of-type(7) {
  animation-delay: 7s;
}

.card:nth-of-type(6) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

.card:nth-of-type(5) {
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

.card:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.card:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.card:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.card:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    filter: blur(1em);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: blur(0);
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cardWrap">
  <div class="card">itin 1</div>
  <div class="card">itin 2</div>
  <div class="card">itin 3</div>
  <div class="card">itin 4</div>
  <div class="card">itin 5</div>
  <div class="card">itin 6</div>
  <div class="card">itin 7</div>
  <div class="card">itin 8</div>
  <div class="card">itin 9</div>
  <div class="card">itin 10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Huh, position absolute/relative works in all browsers. Even IE6 supports it.

Comment: https://www.caniuse.com/#search=position

Comment: Not in this case. Is broking the animation on Safari and Edge.

Answer (score 1):

Invert the order of the animation delay and change the position from absolute to relative in the keyframes.

```css
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 1em;
}

.card {
  animation: slide 0.5s linear both;
  margin-top: 1em;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-5vh);
}

.card:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-delay: 10s;
}

.card:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 9s;
}

.card:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 8s;
}

.card:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: 7s;
}

.card:nth-of-type(5) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

.card:nth-of-type(6) {
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

.card:nth-of-type(7) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.card:nth-of-type(8) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.card:nth-of-type(9) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.card:nth-of-type(10) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    filter: blur(1em);
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: blur(0);
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cardWrap">
  <div class="card">itin 1</div>
  <div class="card">itin 2</div>
  <div class="card">itin 3</div>
  <div class="card">itin 4</div>
  <div class="card">itin 5</div>
  <div class="card">itin 6</div>
  <div class="card">itin 7</div>
  <div class="card">itin 8</div>
  <div class="card">itin 9</div>
  <div class="card">itin 10</div>
</div>
```